# Set Link in table cell with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with three td´s. In the third td I´d like to dynamically set a link in a with data from other two td cells.
I know, how to change the link, but every row get the link from the first row. Maybe a very simple solution, but I´m a little helpless

My Code so far:
**HTML:**

```
<table id="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="one">11</td>
        <td class="two">12</td>
        <td class="three"><a href='#'>13</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="one">21</td>
        <td class="two">22</td>
        <td class="three"><a href="#">23</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var row = $('#table .three a').closest('tr');
  var td = row.find('td');
  var id1 = td.eq(0).text();
  var id2 = td.eq(1).text();
  $('#table .three a').attr("href", "test.html?" + id1 + "-" + id2);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2LbN/)

Comment: '#table .three a' returns two matches, you need an *each()* operation/loop to work on them individually from then on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$('#table .three a').each(function () {
    var id1 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();
    var id2 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
    $(this).prop("href", "test.html?" + id1 + "-" + id2);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/r2LbN/1/)**

Comment: Damn, beaten to the answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

change your javascript to this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {


    $('#table .three a').each(function(){
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        var td = row.find('td');
        var id1 = td.eq(0).text();
        var id2 = td.eq(1).text();
        $(this).attr("href", "test.html?" + id1 + "-" + id2);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
$('#table .three a').each(function (index) {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var td = row.find('td');
    var id1 = td.eq(0).text();
    var id2 = td.eq(1).text();
    $(this).attr("href", "test.html?" + id1 + "-" + id2);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8V36C/)